# cannot load rgl package without manually launching Xapp

Tags: r, rstudio, osx-yosemite, x11, rgl

I initially tried, using RStudio, to install `rgl` using `install.packages("rgl")`, which appeared to have worked. It did give me a message that the binary is older than the source, and that it would install from the binary, but I received no other messages. However `library(rgl)` gets stuck and doesn't do anything.

I removed the package using `remove.packages(rgl)`, and attempted to install from source using `R CMD INSTALL rgl_0.95.1409.tar.gz`. That gets stuck on "testing if installed package can be loaded." I had X11 installed, but I downloaded XQuartz 2.7.8 and tried again, with the same result.

`?rgl::plot3d` in RStudio does take me to the documentation for the `plot3d` function, so I think it installed, just not completely/successfully (`rgl::plot3d` as an attempt to call the `plot3d` function also results in endless computation).

However, I finally did manage to load `rgl` (and use `plot3d`) by manually launching the Xapp from the Terminal prior to loading the library in my current R session (just `X` in Terminal, `xterm` by itself doesn't seem to have the same effect). Can anyone explain why this might be the case, and if there is a workaround to avoid having to manually launch the Xapp? (I do not want to have an application running when I do not need it, but I will also probably sometimes forget to launch the Xapp prior to running this script.)

I'm running OS X Yosemite (10.10.5), RStudio 0.98.1103, R <strike>3.1.3</strike> 3.2.2.

Comment: The R version is considerably out of date, while that version of rgl has a version number higher than the current CRAN release.

Comment: And the current version of RStudio is 0.99.489 although it sounds as though this is probably a version conflict within some combination of old R and bleeding edge of rgl.

Comment: @42- thanks for the heads up, but even after updating R and going back to the rgl binary on CRAN, it doesn't work. What does work, however, is manually launching the Xapp via Terminal prior to attempting to load the rgl package, but I'm not sure why that should be necessary. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: Since first reading this I updated RStudio to Version 0.99.489  (which requires an updated MacTex) and XQuartz and running rgl_0.95.1201 loads without complaint and runs through the demo suite correctly. (R.app GUI 1.66 (6996) crashes on the second demo command without any sort of error message.)

Comment: The rgl package does not use XQuartz but rather opens a separate X11 window. Not being able to launch X(11) automatically makes me think that either your system PATH does not have the X11 server in the search path or an environment variable needs to be fixed. I wasn't able to see any differences in the `Sys.getenv()` results after loading rgl but I see that I have these in my PATH: `/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin1`

Comment: @42- Based on your advice, I looked at my PATH. It included the X11 bin folder, but there were other issues with it - I deleted that portion from the settings in my .bash_profile, and everything works now, without manually launching X11. Thank you very much for sticking with this all afternoon. If you'd like to post your last comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'rgl' package does not use XQuartz, but rather opens a separate X11 window. Not being able to launch X(11) automatically makes me think that either your system PATH does not have the X11 server in the search path or an environment variable needs to be fixed. I wasn't able to see any differences in the `Sys.getenv()` results after loading rgl but I see that I have these in my PATH: `/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin1`

For a while I was rather confused about this as well. The XQuartz.app appeared very similar to the the X11.app , showing up with the very similar icons, (both appearing in the Taskbar as "X".)